# Save data to ViewState

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, viewstate

**I can tried save some data to ViewState, but i get this Error:**
*Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error serializing value 'HeRMeSSAAS.BussinesProcess.BussinesServices.CandidateService' of type 'HeRMeSSAAS.BussinesProcess.BussinesServices.CandidateService.'*
Code:

```
private IActionService ActionService
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["ActionService"] as IActionService;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ActionService"] = value;
        }
    }

private void InitializeField(IActionService service)
        {
            ActionService = service;
        }
```

How i can store value to ViewState?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

s your HeRMeSSAAS.BussinesProcess.BussinesServices.CandidateService decorated with the Serializable attribute?

eg:

```
[Serializable]
public class CandidateService
{

}
```

if this is not a very simple class I would also recommend storing it in the Session rather than the ViewState as it will take longer for the page to download and render

Answer (score 1):

you need the [Serializable] Attribute on top of your business object.